# MATLAB ode45 graph changes dramatically when interval increases

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, ode

I'm using MATLAB to graph the Lorenz system. Essentially, I have

```
r=31;
x0 = [(-9+sqrt(81+40*r)).*10^-27 (2*r).*10^-27 0];
flor = @(t,s) [ -10*(s(1)-s(2)); r*s(1)-s(2)-s(1)*s(3); 
-8/3*s(3)+s(1)*s(2)];
[t1,s1] = ode45(flor,(0:0.0005:30), x0);

subplot(2,1,1),
hold on
plot3(s1(:,1),s1(:,2),s1(:,3))
hold off
grid on
xlabel('x'),ylabel('y'),zlabel('z')
view(10,5)
axis tight
```

Now, when run the above, I get the figure[image]

However, when I change `ode45(flor,(0:0.0005:30), x0)` to `ode45(flor,(0:0.0005:31), x0)` (that is, I change 30 to 31), I get the following figure[image]

Which is drastically different! The only thing that I am changing (unless I am mistaken) is the time interval by 1. Any clue as to why this is happeing?

Comment: Hmmm, i just tried it with 30 and 31 and got the same graph. I am using R2017a.

Comment: Chaotic systems are known to be chaotic.

Comment: @qbzenker Interesting. I am using R2016b. I'll try updating.

Comment: @TroyHaskin True, but it should be the same plot, just with some more tail. I can't see why anything in the [0,30] range would change.

Comment: I know.  I just wanted to make a funny.  It probably has something to do with the dense output routine; I *am* looking into it.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit appears to be the default maximum time step.  By default, `ode45` uses [`0.1*abs(diff(tspan))`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#input_argument_d0e709267), which may be used early when the simulation is not oscillating wildly.  And since the two simulations have a different final time, the maximum will be different, and the small changes in the time march will be amplified by the time evolution of the chaotic system.  Setting the maximum to the same value for both simulations gives the same results.

This code

```
r=31;
x0 = [(-9+sqrt(81+40*r)).*10^-27 (2*r).*10^-27 0];
flor = @(t,s) [ -10*(s(1)-s(2)); r*s(1)-s(2)-s(1)*s(3); 
-8/3*s(3)+s(1)*s(2)];
[t30,s30]   = ode45(flor,0:0.0005:30, x0);
[t31,s31]   = ode45(flor,0:0.0005:31, x0);
[t30p,s30p] = ode45(flor,0:0.0005:30, x0, odeset('MaxStep',3));
[t31p,s31p] = ode45(flor,0:0.0005:31, x0, odeset('MaxStep',3));

subplot(2,2,1);
    plot3(s30(:,1),s30(:,2),s30(:,3));
    grid on
    xlabel('x'),ylabel('y'),zlabel('z')
    view(10,5)
    axis tight
    title('30 Seconds: Default Maximum Time-Step');
subplot(2,2,2);
    plot3(s31(t31<=30,1),s31(t31<=30,2),s31(t31<=30,3));
    grid on
    xlabel('x'),ylabel('y'),zlabel('z')
    view(10,5)
    axis tight
    title('31 Seconds: Default Maximum Time-Step');
subplot(2,2,3);
    plot3(s30p(:,1),s30p(:,2),s30p(:,3));
    grid on
    xlabel('x'),ylabel('y'),zlabel('z')
    view(10,5)
    axis tight
    title('30 Seconds: Maximum Time-Step of 3');
subplot(2,2,4);
    plot3(s31p(t31p<=30,1),s31p(t31p<=30,2),s31p(t31p<=30,3));
    grid on
    xlabel('x'),ylabel('y'),zlabel('z')
    view(10,5)
    axis tight
    title('31 Seconds: Maximum Time-Step of 3');
```

produces this graph

[image: Lorenz System comparison of maximum step sizes]

As can be seen, matching the maximum time step (the graphs on the bottom) produces the same output.

Comment: Nice catch! Now, I just have to wait for the new version of MATLAB to finish downloading on my laptop before I can fix that, haha. Thank you for taking the time to look into it!

Comment: @Bonnaduck Not a problem. The real fun is in decreasing the maximum step and seeing the results still change.  The graphs between `1E-2` and `1E-3` are comparable.  This is probably something you should look into to ensure your results are rock solid.